# Can't load image by data binding (@BindingAdapter) : AAPT: error: attribute

Tags: android, android-databinding

Android Studio 3.6

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    dataBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
```

In some class e.g. MyAdapter I create public static method `loadImage` with annotation `@BindingAdapter`:

```
public class MyAdapter extends DataBindingRecyclerViewAdapter {

    public MyAdapter(Context context, List<?> data) {
        super(context, data);
    }

    @Override
    protected int getLayoutForPosition(int position) {
        return R.layout.forecast_data_list_item;
    }

    @BindingAdapter({"app:weatherImage"})
    public static void loadImage(ImageView view, String imageUrl) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
                .load(imageUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().circleCrop())
                .into(view);
    }

}
```

in xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>
        <variable
            name="model"
            type="com.myproject.model.SomeModel" />
    </data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/invoiceMainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_default_margin"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/containerRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:weatherImage="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/11111?s=200x200"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

But I get compile error:

```
AAPT: error: attribute weatherImage (aka com.myproject:weatherImage) not found.
```

Comment: can you try removing app: from your Binding adapter method. So instead you this `@BindingAdapter({"app:weatherImage"})` you just do this `@BindingAdapter({"weatherImage"})`

Comment: app:weatherImage="@{http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/11111?s=200x200}"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your BindingAdapter

```
 @BindingAdapter("app:weatherImage")
    @JvmStatic
    fun setSelectedBackGround(view: ImageView, imageUrl: String) {
        Glide.with(view.getContext())
            .load(imageUrl).apply(new RequestOptions().circleCrop())
            .into(view);
    }
```

and in your XMl use it like this

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="96dp"
            android:layout_height="96dp"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/half_default_margin"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@drawable/default_image"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/containerRight"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:weatherImage="@{`http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/11111?s=200x200`}"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to change this line to something like

```
  app:weatherImage="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/11111?s=200x200"
```

to something like

```
  app:weatherImage='@{@string/image_url_link}'
```